# Same way to split string but get different result

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to split two different string. I use the same way, but i get the different results.
It's spent me a lot of time to find problem.
Is there any way to solve this ? Thanks!

1. Excepted Result:

```
// data = 36191d2a 9.18 1.41
vector<string> SplitRecvData(string data){
   vector<string> words{};
   char delimiter = ' ';
   istringstream iss(data);

   copy(
   std::istream_iterator<string>(iss),
   std::istream_iterator<string>(),
   std::back_inserter(words));
   vector<string> splitData = words;

   for(int i=0;i<splitData.size();i++) {
      cout << "i= " << ", " << splitData[i] << endl;
   }

   return splitData;
}
// Result
i= 0, 36191d2a
i= 1, 9.18
i= 2, 1.41
```

2. Not Excepted Result:

```
// data = Hum,Temp,Time
vector<string> SplitSubTopic(string data){
   vector<string> words{};
   char delimiter = ',';
   istringstream iss(data);

   copy(
   std::istream_iterator<string>(iss),
   std::istream_iterator<string>(),
   std::back_inserter(words));
   vector<string> splitData = words;

   for(int i=0;i<splitData.size();i++) {
      cout << "i= " << ", " << splitData[i] << endl;
   }

   return splitData;
}
// Result
i= 0, Hum,Temp,Time
```

Comment: Remove all those escape sequences (`\<\>`) please. Provide a [mcve] as required here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm didn't notice that.

Comment: Have you noticed that you never use the `delimiter` variable for anything?

Comment: It is a bad idea to define two functions that do the exact same thing. Create one instead (and give the delimiter as a parameter of the function). Moreover, as already pointed out, you are actually not using the delimiter variable...

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the delimiter, this instead should work

```
istringstream my_stream(data);

// To store the stream string
string token;

size_t pos = -1;

// Traverse till stream is valid
while (my_stream >> token) {

    // If ',' is found then tokenize the string token
    while ((pos = token.rfind(',')) != std::string::npos) {
        token.erase(pos, 1);
    }

    // Print the tokenize string
    cout << token << '\n';
}
```